# Is it a bad practice to return a std container from a interface class?

Tags: c++

I have meet such a question.

I need to design a interface class, which looks like to be

```
struct IIDs
{
    ....
    const std::set<int>& getAllIDs() = 0;  //!< I want the collection of int to be sorted.

}

void foo()
{
    const std::set<int>& ids = pIIDs->getAllIDs();
    for(std::set<int>::const_iterator it = ids.begin();....;..) {
         // do something
    }
}
```

I think that return a std's container is a bit of inappropriate, for that it will force the implement to use a std::set to store the value of IDs, But If I write it as follow :

```
struct IIDs
{
    ....
    int count() const = 0;
    int at(int index) = 0;    //!< the itmes should be sorted
}

void foo()
{
   for (int i = 0; i < pIIDs->count(); ++i) {
       int val = pIIDs->at(u);
       ...
   }
}
```

I found that none of the std's containers could provide those requests:

1. the complexity of index lookup needed to less or equal than O(log n).
2. the complexity of insertion need to less or equal than O(log n).
3. the items must be sorted.

So I just have to use the example.1, Is those can be acceptable?

Comment: I think the answer to this question may be different depending on the type of container. It's OK to return strings and (usually) vectors, but I would not encourage returning, say, a multimap.

Comment: Do you actually mean 'less than O(log n)' or 'less than or equal to O(log n)'?  Because std::set is O(log n) for insertion and lookup.

Comment: @Mehrdad: that's the kind of assertion that could use some supporting reasoning/links/references etc. (and - I'd hazard - qualification).

Comment: @TonyD: Well, that's why I didn't post it as an answer, because I didn't have foolproof reasoning for it. It's not a hard and fast rule, but generally the most intuitive way to expose a string is to just use the STL type. On the other hand, this is less likely to be true for sets/maps. That said, I'm **not** talking about dynamic linking here, so don't try to combine what I said with ABI compatibility and such, those are different problems. I'm purely talking about it from an interface design perspective here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**STL containers and template code in general should never be used across a DLL boundary.**

The thing you have to keep in mind when returning complex types like STL containers is that if your call ever crosses the boundary between two different DLLs (or a DLL and an application) running different memory managers your application will most likely crash spectacularly.

The templates that make up the STL code will be executed within the implementation DLL, creating all the memory used by the container there.  Later when it leaves scope in your calling code, your own memory manager will attempt to deallocate memory it doesn't own, resulting in a crash.

If you know your code won't cross DLL boundaries, and will only ever be called in the context of a single memory manager, then you're fine as far as memory management is concerned.

However, even in cases where you're only returning references, such as your example above, where the lifetime of the container would be entirely managed by the interface implementation code, unless you know that the exact same version of the STL and the exact same compiler and linker settings were used for compiling the implementation as the caller, you're asking for trouble.

Comment: absolutely, not only that, but a myriad of compiling issues, like padding/packing setup, or _SCL_ITERATOR_DEBUG (forgot exact spell) and stuff like that can go horribly wrong as well. upvote.

Comment: ... who said anything about DLLs here though?

Answer (score 1):

The problem i see is you are returning the collection by const references, that mean that you have a member of that collection type and are returning a reference to it, if you are returning a local variable to the function (invalid memory access problems).

If it's a member variable is better provide access to begin and end iterator. If is local variable you could returned by value (C++11 should optimize and no copy anything). If it's DLL boundary try for all mean not use any C++ types, only C types.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of design, and for good generic code, prefer the STL way: return iterators, leaving the container type an implementation detail of `IIDs`, and hide your types with `typdef`s

```
struct IIDs
{
    typedef std::set<int> Container;
    typedef Container::iterator IDIterator;

    // We only expose iterators to the data
    IDIterator begin();  //!< I want the collection of int to be sorted.
    IDIterator end(); 
    // ... 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various approaches:

- if you want to minimise the coupling of client code on the `IIDs` implementation and ensure iteration is completed while the `IIDs` object still exists, then use a visitor pattern: the calling code just has to supply some function to be called for each of the member elements in turn and is not responsible for the iteration itself

Visitor example:

```
struct IIDs
{
    template <typename T>
    void visit(T& t)
    {
        for (int i : ids_) t(i);
    }
    ...
  private:
    std::set<int> ids_;
};
```

- if you want to give the caller more freedom to mix other code in with the container traversal, and have multiple concurrent independent traversals, then provide iterators, but be aware that the client code could keep an iterator hanging around longer than the `IIDs` object itself - you may or may not want to handle that scenario gracefully